# Need to combine info from two different files of different lengths

Tags: r, merge

I have two data files, data frames 'cap' and 'id'. Data frame 'cap' containes information on certain individuals for various seasons, the name of the individual being in the first column, the next 11 columns being observational info for 11 consecutive years. The second dataframe, 'id', contains three columns, i.e. the individual names, their sex, and one index for this individual. I need to combine the information in these two files so in order to end up with one file with name, sex, index, and then the 11 columns with seasonal information:

NAME  SEX  INDEX  SEASON01  SEASON02 SEASON03...

The problem is that these files are of different lengths, and the names are even sorted differently, so the script need to check that the name in the first column is the correct one before merging the information for each record.

Any help appreciated.

Sample 'cap':

```
structure(list(name = c("K1", "K2", "KI01", "KI03", "KI05", "KI07", 
"KI08", "NKW-001", "NKW-002", "NKW-003", "NKW-004", "NKW-006", 
"NKW-007", "NKW-008", "NKW-009", "NKW-010", "NKW-011", "NKW-013", 
"NKW-014", "NKW-015", "NKW-016", "NKW-017", "NKW-018", "NKW-019", 
"NKW-021", "NKW-022", "NKW-023", "NKW-024", "NKW-025", "NKW-026", 
"NKW-028", "NKW-030", "NKW-031", "NKW-032", "NKW-033", "NKW-034", 
"NKW-035", "NKW-036", "NKW-037", "NKW-038", "NKW-039", "NKW-040", 
"NKW-041", "NKW-042", "NKW-043", "NKW-044", "NKW-045", "NKW-046", 
"NKW-047", "NKW-048", "NKW-049", "NKW-050", "NKW-051", "NKW-052", 
"NKW-053", "NKW-054", "NKW-055", "NKW-056", "NKW-058", "NKW-059", 
"NKW-060", "NKW-061", "NKW-062", "NKW-063", "NKW-064", "NKW-065", 
"NKW-068", "NKW-069", "NKW-070", "NKW-071", "NKW-072", "NKW-073", 
"NKW-074", "NKW-076", "NKW-077", "NKW-078", "NKW-079", "NKW-080", 
"NKW-081", "NKW-082", "NKW-083", "NKW-084", "NKW-085", "NKW-086", 
"NKW-087", "NKW-088", "NKW-089", "NKW-090"), season01 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), season02 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), season03 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), season04 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), season05 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), season06 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), season07 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), season08 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
), season09 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), season10 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), season11 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -88L))
```

Sample 'id':

```
structure(list(name = c("K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "KI01", "KI02", 
"KI03", "KI05", "KI06", "KI07", "KI08", "KI10", "NKW-0001", "NKW-0002", 
"NKW-0003", "NKW-0004", "NKW-0005", "NKW-0006", "NKW-0007", "NKW-0008", 
"NKW-0009", "NKW-0010", "NKW-0011", "NKW-0012", "NKW-0013", "NKW-0014", 
"NKW-0015", "NKW-0016", "NKW-0017", "NKW-0018", "NKW-0019", "NKW-0020", 
"NKW-0021", "NKW-0022", "NKW-0023", "NKW-0024", "NKW-0025", "NKW-0026", 
"NKW-0027", "NKW-0028", "NKW-0029", "NKW-0030", "NKW-0031", "NKW-0032", 
"NKW-0033", "NKW-0034", "NKW-0035", "NKW-0036", "NKW-0037", "NKW-0038", 
"NKW-0039", "NKW-0040", "NKW-0041", "NKW-0042", "NKW-0043", "NKW-0044", 
"NKW-0045", "NKW-0046", "NKW-0047", "NKW-0048", "NKW-0049", "NKW-0050", 
"NKW-0051", "NKW-0052", "NKW-0053", "NKW-0054", "NKW-0055", "NKW-0056", 
"NKW-0057", "NKW-0058", "NKW-0059", "NKW-0060", "NKW-0061", "NKW-0062", 
"NKW-0063", "NKW-0064", "NKW-0065", "NKW-0066", "NKW-0067", "NKW-0068", 
"NKW-0069", "NKW-0070", "NKW-0071", "NKW-0072", "NKW-0073", "NKW-0074", 
"NKW-0075", "NKW-0076", "NKW-0077", "NKW-0078", "NKW-0079", "NKW-0080", 
"NKW-0081", "NKW-0082", "NKW-0083", "NKW-0084", "NKW-0085", "NKW-0086", 
"NKW-0087", "NKW-0088", "NKW-0089", "NKW-0090"), sex = c("F", 
"M", "M", "U", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "U", "M", "U", "M", 
"M", "M", "U", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "U", "U", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "U", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "U", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), index = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))
```

Comment: Try `mydf3 <- bind_rows(mydf1,mydf2)` with your dataframes. This function belongs to `dplyr` package!

Comment: Or you could try one of the `join()` functions in `dplyr`, like `left_join(id, cap)`, but in the data your provided the names in `cap` have one leading zero after NKW- and the names in `id` have two leading zeros after NKW-.

Comment: This is precisely a "merge" operation. If @DaveArmstrong's concern is true, that is the `name` used to identify a particular subject is formatted differently in the two frames, then that is something that must be addressed before merging. However, if there really is a difference between `"NKW-008"` and `"NKW-0008"`, then this is precisely a merge/join operation, and therefore a dupe of either/both: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.

Comment: That is, either `merge(id, cap, by = "name")` or `dplyr::inner_join(id, cap, by = "name")`. You need to decide if you want to keep entries that do not exist in both frames, with `all`/`all.x`/`all.y` arguments in `merge`, or the functions `dplyr::full_join`, `dplyr::left_join`, and `dplyr::right_join`, respectively.